# Vuex - Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers. State changed inside mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm calling a store action from the main layout (nuxt.js default.vue)
I'm then calling a state mutation within the mutations export. Why am I getting this error?

Error in console: http://prntscr.com/rwvfjf

Code:

default.vue

```js
created () {
  this.$store.dispatch("update_user");
  ...
}
```

Store (store/index.js)

```js
export const state = {
  ...
  state: null, 
}

export const actions {
  ...
  update_user({commit}) {commit("update_user")}
}

export const mutations = {
  async update_user(state) {
    if (state.token == undefined) {
      return
    }
    if (this.$axios.defaults.headers.common["authorization"] == undefined) {
      this.$axios.defaults.headers.common["authorization"] = state.token
    }
    var user = await this.$axios.get("/api/v1/user/@me");
    state.user = user;
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-must-be-synchronous):

> **Mutations Must Be Synchronous**
>
> One important rule to remember is that mutation handler functions must be synchronous

It looks like you have them reversed.  Restructure your action and mutation to:

Action

```js
export const actions = {  // <-- was missing an equals
  ...
  async update_user({ state, commit }) { // <-- state and commit needed
    if (state.token == undefined) {
      return
    }
    if (this.$axios.defaults.headers.common["authorization"] == undefined) {
      this.$axios.defaults.headers.common["authorization"] = state.token
    }
    var user = await this.$axios.get("/api/v1/user/@me");
    commit("update_user", user); // <-- Passing the user data to the mutation
  }
}
```

Mutation

```js
export const mutations = {
  update_user(state, user) {
    state.user = user;
  },
}
```

Also notice, the async action returns data that is then passed to the mutation, where it's set to state.  You may have an error with `this.$axios` too, once that's fixed.  If so, make sure you're importing it:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

and using it like:

```js
if (axios.defaults.headers.common["authorization"] == undefined) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common["authorization"] = state.token
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This sorted it.